# Position of door stop vs lock striker plate

Tags: doors, lock

When positioning the door stop after installing a lock set striker plate on an interior door (e.g. bathroom, bedroom etc) should I give the door more wiggle room (the striker plate allows the latch to go back and forth about 1/4") or make it more snug? I like the snug idea but would also like to provide some room for possible warping in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a little wiggle room this is good. You can take out wiggle by bending out (into the hole) the tab that goes into the hole. Most that I have seen have a little slot for inserting a flat blade screwdriver to bend the tab out to take up wiggle.

But be careful not to bend it into the hole too far. If you overshoot, the bolt will hang up, and bending it back away from the bolt may require some ingenuity and trial and error.